# How do I integrate a partial differential equation with a constant quantity?

Tags: integration, functions, partial-differential-equations

If I have a partial differential equation of the form:

$$\left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_{p/x} = -\frac{k \hspace{1mm}z(p/x)}{x} + \frac{ky}{x}$$

*where the $p/x$ subscript represents that this quantity must be kept constant. And $z$ is a function of this quantity.*

**How do I integrate an equation of this form?**

I know that if it wasn't a partial differential equation I could simply integrate using an integration factor.

But because it is a p.d.e. I  feel like an extra term should arrive, something that doesn't depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p/x$ is constant, so is $z(p/x)$. Just treat it as a regular ODE, just keep in mind your constants (in particular, integrating constants) will end up depending on the other variables.

Comment: Does that mean that after integrating I will have an extra functions depending on $p/x$? *e.g.* $f(p/x)$